# How to find how many keys are in array?

Tags: php, arrays, json

I did this to find out how many `value` in Array.

```
$forExample = '{"sik1":"hello","sik2":"world","sik10":"today","sik41":"yesterday"}';
```

*In the example above, there are a total of 4 values.*

I tried it;

```
$test = json_decode($forExample);
        $rows = count($test); 

        for ($valueCount = 0;
             $valueCount < $rows;
             $valueCount ++) {
            if ($rows) {
                if ($test->{'sik'[$valueCount]} != '') {
                    echo $test->{'sik'[$valueCount]};
                }
            }
        }
```

Where do I make the mistake?

Comment: if you use `json_decode($forExample, true);` the json will be transformed into an associated array. Then you can use all the array functions provided by php. e.g. `array_unique`

Comment: Tell whoever is sending you this garbage to use an array instead of foo1...fooN keys.

Comment: Also the if($row) is redundant since the for loop won't run when count = 0

Comment: @kuh-chan I tried but no change result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't print the complete values from your `json` using your logic.

First issues is, you are taking count of `json` `object` which will give you error like.

> Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in..

But of-course you can take count if you do like this `json_decode($forExample, true);` which will converted to associative `array` and take `count`.

**There is a logic issue with your `for` loop even if you get the count of the array like I suggested above,**

So the `count` is 4. You loop and finds its key using the `$valueCount` which will go `0` to `3`. As per your logic the keys will be like `sik0`, `sik1`, `sik2` and `sik3` but actual keys are `sik1`, `sik2`, `sik10` and `sik41`. So you will get only `sik1` and `sik2`.

**Solution**

Use `foreach` loop

```
<?php

$forExample = '{"sik1":"hello","sik2":"world","sik10":"today","sik41":"yesterday"}';
$test = json_decode($forExample);

foreach ($test as $key => $value){
    echo $key, ' => ', $value;
    echo '<br>';
}

?>
```

**Output**

```
sik1 => hello
sik2 => world
sik10 => today
sik41 => yesterday
```

Comment: With one word, perfect!

Comment: Cool! Happy Programming! Do up-vote too ;)

Answer (score 1):

You have to add true as a second argument to the `json_decode($json, true)` which will return an array.

And `count(array_keys ($array))` will return the keys count in the array.

Please do check the documentation for the expected behavior of the functions.